# Palindrome Java: While and If/Else Statements

Tags: java, while-loop, reverse, palindrome

My code keeps printing out "true" no matter what I enter. My code does not show any errors, I enter 56 as the input and it still prints "true." I'm having a really hard time figuring out why. Also, I'm new to Java as well as Stack Overflow. Any help would be appreciated.

//Palindrome verification

```
    temp = integer;
    while (integer > 0)
    {
        remainder = integer%10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        integer=integer /10;
    }

    if (integer==reverse)

        System.out.println("True");
        else
        System.out.println("False");
```

Comment: Why don't you let us know what you have done till now and then maybe people can help you with your efforts. "What is wrong with it" is not acceptable on SO
I see the problem is a very simple one and if you run the code in debug mode, you will find the solution immediately.

Comment: @Nishit Sorry! I'm new to Java and SO, I will remember that for next time. And thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Appreciate it man! And as much as it helps us save time, it also helps you, the seeker to try and learn new things. Ready made solutions are never appreciated until the effort to get them is put in. All the best :)

Comment: @tonybolt your program always returns true?? or does it always return false?

Comment: @amrendersingh Always returns true!!

Comment: @tonybolt Please post some more code, because as per your current code it should always return false, since your if statement always executes to false.

Comment: It prints "True" when `integer==reverse`; we know `integer` has been reduced to zero, so `reverse` must also be zero.  `reverse` should only be zero if `integer` was initially zero.  So are you sure that `integer` contains your input number at the beginning?  We're not seeing that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your program when while loop completely execute `integer` variable value will become zero and it is the problem. 
you need to change `if (integer==reverse)` to `if (temp==reverse)`.

complete code:

```
public class palindrom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int integer = 122; //change this value according to your preference
        int temp = integer;
        int remainder;
        int reverse = 0;
        while (integer > 0){
            remainder = integer%10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        integer=integer /10;
    }

    if (temp==reverse)
        System.out.println("True");
    else
        System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need compare START value with REVERSE. In your code (integer==reverse) will always be FALSE, because integer==0 after cycle in while.

```
        int integer = 12344321;
        int remainder, reverse = 0;

        int start = integer;
        while (integer > 0)
        {
            remainder = integer%10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            integer = integer / 10;
        }

        if (start==reverse)
            System.out.println("True");
        else
            System.out.println("False");
        System.out.println(reverse);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest, but it is still returning "true" for input 56.

Comment: I just put 56 as init value and it shows me False. Just copy my code to main() method - and you will see. I think you have one of this a) forget to init start before cycle b) compare integer==reverse instead of start==reverse